# Realtek Wi-Fi and Bluetooth both are not detected in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu on my new laptop and I do not see either the wifi or the bluetooth.

I looked for my wireless card (Realtek RTL8723DE) and I have not found anything.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: The `rtl8723de` is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

The device is currently supported. See the [github repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/extended) for instructions.

To my knowlegde the WiFi is working, but I'm not sure about the BT.